# CSS wont center my elements if I put a font awesome icon

Tags: html, css

I have this here that is supposed to show the check font awesome icon side by side with the in stock text, but when I do this it doesnt show in the center but it shows near the center.

```css
.grid-container {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="grid-container">
    <h4 style="width:50%;margin:0 auto;">
        <span class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>&nbsp;In stock
    </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @Pika, do you have a screenshot of what happens?

Comment: It shows up near the right side of the screen, but not in the center

Comment: text-align:center;

Comment: @Pika a screenshot would really help, because I am not sure what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

You've to `display: block` the `.grid-container`

```
.grid-container{ display: block; margin: 0 auto;}
```